# CakeResque - Resque not found in ...app/Plugin/CakeResque/Lib/CakeResque.php on line 82

Tags: php, cakephp

CakeResque - Resque not found in ...app/Plugin/CakeResque/Lib/CakeResque.php on line 82

I've followed the instructions here: http://cakeresque.kamisama.me/install#requirements to setup CakeResque with my CakePHP project but the Resque class isn't loading.  I installed CakeResque using Composer and I'm assuming I'm missing something (possible autoloader) but with no luck.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running `php composer.phar update`?

Comment: Thanks Brobin.  Yes, I had run composer update but my issue was that I missed a step in the instructions and was not requiring Vendor/autoloader.php in my app/Config/core file.

Answer (score 0):

Got help at github.  I had missed adding composer autoloader in my app/Config/core.php per the instructions.

Comment: Can you explain how did you accomplish?

Comment: @ozanmuyes follow the instructions on the [installation page](http://cakeresque.kamisama.me/install).  It includes the instructions to add autoloader to core.php file.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the vendor directory is mentioned in the `app/composer.json`

```
{
    "require": {
        "kamisama/cake-resque": "^4.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "Vendor"
    }
}
```

in the `app/Config/core.php` require the autoload

```
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/Vendor/autoload.php';
```